# Change children property when parent property changes in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qt-creator

I have 3 files. main.qml, Guide.qml and ChannelViewer.qml
my main class contains 2 components and a loader here is the code

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id:loader
    color: "black"
    property string channelName
    property string channelURL

    Component{
        id:tv
        ChannelViewer{}
    }

    Component{
        id:guide
        Guide{}
    }

    Loader
    {
        id: pageLoader
        anchors.fill:parent
        focus:true
        sourceComponent: tv
    }

    Connections{
        target:pageLoader.item
        onChangeChannel:{
            channelName=name
            channelURL=url
        }
    }

    Keys.onPressed: {
        event.accepted = true;
        if (event.key === Qt.Key_I) {
            pageLoader.sourceComponent = tv;
        }
        else if(event.key === Qt.Key_G) {
            pageLoader.sourceComponent = guide;
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I press "G" I would be moved to the guide file without any issues In my guide page I am able to send signal to main.qml and update the name property in main.

**Guide.qml**

```
Item {
    signal changeChannel(string url, string name)
    Loader {
        id: pageLoader
        anchors.fill:parent
        sourceComponent: guide
        focus:true
    }

    Keys.onPressed: {
        if(event.key === Qt.Key_Escape) {
            pageLoader.source = "main.qml";
        }
        event.accepted = true;
    }

    Component {
        id:guide

        Rectangle {
            color:"lightblue"

            Keys.onPressed: {
                if(event.key === Qt.Key_Return) {
                    changeChannel(menuContent.currentItem.ch_url, menuContent.currentItem.ch_name)
                    pageLoader.source = "main.qml";
                }
                event.accepted = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However now when I press "Return" in my Guide.qml i will be taken back to main.qml (Channelname and ChannelURL will be updated successfully), and my main.qml will now take me to ChannelViewer.qml and here is the problem my ChannelViewer.qml will not receive the updated channelName and channelURL. And I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

**ChannelViewer.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import VLCQt 1.0

Rectangle {
    id:root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: "black"
    focus:true

    Loader
    {
        id: pageLoader
        anchors.fill:parent
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            console.log(channelURL)
        }
    }

    Keys.onPressed: {
        if (event.key === Qt.Key_I) {
            event.accepted = true;
            if(channelInfo.visible === true) {
                channelInfo.visible=false;
            }
            else {
                channelInfo.visible=true;
            }
        }
    }

    VlcVideoPlayer {
        id: vidwidget
        anchors.fill: parent
        url:channelURL

        ChannelInfo{
            id:channelInfo
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.bottomMargin: ((parent.height*5)/100)
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            width:parent.width - ((parent.width*10)/100)
            height: (parent.height*20)/100
            backgroundOpacity: 0.7
            radius:10
            channelNameProp: channelName
            channelNumberProp: "1"
            headerIcon: "imgs/television_32x32.png"
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Code for my ChannelInfo.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id:channelinfo
    property color backgroundColor: "blue"
    property color headerBackgroundColor: "lightblue"
    property color headerNameColor: "black"
    property color borderColor: "black"
    property color channelNameColor: "white"
    property color channelNumberColor: "white"
    property real borderWidth:0
    property real radius:0
    property real backgroundOpacity: 0.5
    property string menuTitle : "TV Channels"
    property string channelNameProp
    property string channelNumberProp
    property url headerIcon: "imgs/television.png"

    visible:false

    Rectangle{
        id:root
        width:channelinfo.width
        height:channelinfo.height
        color:channelinfo.backgroundColor
        border.color:channelinfo.borderColor
        border.width: channelinfo.borderWidth
        radius:channelinfo.radius
        opacity:channelinfo.backgroundOpacity
        visible: parent.visible

        Rectangle{
            id:header
            anchors.top:parent.top
            //            width:(parent.width*40)/100
            width: parent.width
            height: (parent.height*30)/100
            radius: channelinfo.radius
            color:channelinfo.headerBackgroundColor
            Image{
                source:channelinfo.headerIcon
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: 10
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                anchors.verticalCenterOffset: -4
            }

            Text{
                id:headerTitle
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: 50
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                width:parent.width
                wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                color:channelinfo.headerNameColor
                text:menuTitle
                font.pixelSize: Math.round(parent.height/2)
                font.bold: true
            }
        }

        Rectangle{
            id:content
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            width:parent.width
            height:parent.height-header.height
            color:"transparent"
            Text{
                id:channelName
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: 50
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                color:channelinfo.channelNameColor
                text:channelNameProp
                font.pixelSize: Math.round(parent.height/4)
                font.bold: true
            }
            Text{
                id:channelNumber
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.rightMargin: 20
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                color:channelinfo.channelNumberColor
                text:channelNumberProp
                font.pixelSize: Math.round(parent.height/4)
                font.bold: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Github Page for VLCPlayer
https://github.com/vlc-qt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to have such a fixed structure, why even bother with the signal, you can simply:

```
 Keys.onPressed: {
                if(event.key === Qt.Key_Return) {
                    channelName = menuContent.currentItem.ch_name
                    channelURL = menuContent.currentItem.ch_url
                    pageLoader.source = "main.qml";
                }
                event.accepted = true;
            }
```

And then remove the unnecessary part:

```
Connections{
    target:pageLoader.item
    onChangeChannel:{
        channelName=name
        channelURL=url
    }
}
```

Since `channelName` and `channelURL` are declared in the root object of the qml file, they should be accessible from within objects that are nested further up the tree because of dynamic scoping.

So after you posted the relevant code, you have an:

```
        Text{
            id:channelName
```

in your `ChannelInfo` object, which is shadowing the `channelName` property, declared in `main.qml`. It is a good idea to develop the habit of consistent naming conventions. For example, since this is an id, I personally would have used `id: _cName`, this way you minimize the odds of getting such collisions.

Update:

The only other reason I can think why it doesn't work is that you are somewhere breaking the `channelNameProp: channelName` binding by doing something like `channelNameProp = something`.

Here is a quick example to illustrate that dynamic scoping *just works* (as long as you don't shadow anything), even in situations that involve dynamically changing Loader items:

```
// main.qml
ApplicationWindow {
  id: _cName
  visible: true
  width: 640
  height: 480
  property int value: 0
  Loader {
    id: loader
    source: "Obj.qml"
  }
}

// Rect.qml
Rectangle {
  id: rectangle
  width: 50; height: 100
  color: "red"
  Text {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    text: value
  }
  MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
      loader.source = "Obj.qml"
    }
  }
}

// Obj.qml
Rectangle {
  id: rectangle
  width: 50; height: 100
  color: "blue"
  MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
      value++
      loader.source = "Rect.qml"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer the signal as you should strive to avoid relying on dynamic scoping. A bidirectional binding might be nicer, but the signal is IMHO a good start.

Comment: "as you should strive to avoid relying on dynamic scoping" - why?

Comment: before binding I tried this and it didn't work as well. I gave it another try and still the same. main.qml gets the updated values from Guide.qml however, ChannelViewer doesn't get the updated values.

Comment: Well, it should work, there is something wrong with your code if it doesn't.

Comment: Also, using dynamic scoping in this particular instance is 100% ok, and since it is so static it doesn't even merit using signals to "component-alize" for reusability, since there is no such thing in this scenario. Dynamic scoping has overheads, but those are at play only when using deep trees and frequent binding updates, which this use case doesn't have.

Comment: @MuhandJumah Does `ChannelInfo` by **some chance** happen to have a `channelName` property, which will shadow the one in the lower scope?

Comment: Because it seems like he has already a problem with the dynamic scoping. It seems like the channelName is shadowed somewhere, otherwise the update would propagate. In a example it might look good and work, but as soon as you change some things it might break and then it is a lot of work to find all the dependencies you have.

Comment: @dtech what I have posted is my exact code. I am not able to find the issue.

Comment: @derM I will give it a try in a clean project and let you know

Comment: I posted my ChannelInfo in the original post

Comment: You have a `id:channelName` for a `Text` element in the info, that's what's shadowing the channelName that you think you are binding to.

Comment: @dtech removed it and still same issue.

Comment: Well, try running qmake manually, if that doesn't work I am out of ideas. The code should work.

Comment: @dtech is not shadowing issue. I confirmed by creating a different property called ch in ChannelsModel.qml then in my main.qml I changed its value to "test" and it worked; however, when the value changes dynamically then it wont update and it would stay as "test" if that doesn't make sense i can post the code.

Comment: So now there is a `ChannelsModel` too?

Comment: My apologize I meant ChannelViewer.qml , no I dont have ChannelsModel.qml

Comment: Well, as I said many times over, it should work. You are doing something wrong if it doesn't. Maybe you are not quite read to use QML in production and still need to do more learning, that much is evident from your poor design style. I suggest going through https://qmlbook.github.io/, and good luck.

Comment: @dtech I was able to solve it. Removing Keys.onPressed from main.qml solved the issue. Not quite sure why it was not working but i will investigate it further. Thanks.

Comment: it's my 2nd day learning QML. This is not an application for production but more to learn. I am going through the book. But anyways, thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, you should keep things simple and gradually step up, this way you avoid such unproductive frustrations.

Comment: You do something very very strange. You load `Guide.qml` in a loader in `main.qml`. Then in `Guid.qml` you use a loader to load the actual component. On the key event, you use that loader to load `main.qml`, so you have `main.qml -loaded-> Guide.qml -loaded-> main.qml` . What is your intention with that?

Comment: @derM dynamic scoping should work even in that case, but yes, that's one of the many design issues with that code, it is pretty much a mess :)

Answer (score 0):

As the properties

```
property string channelName
property string channelURL
```

have change signals and therefore support property binding, I think the easiest way would be to change line 9-17 to

```
Component{
    id:tv
    ChannelViewer {
        id: channelViewer
        channelName: loader.channelName
        channelURL: loader.channelURL
    }
}

Component{
    id:guide
    Guide {
        id: guide
        channelName: loader.channelName
        channelURL: loader.channelURL
    }
}
```

If Guide changes the channelName you need to make sure that you change it in the `loader`. You might use `Binding`-objects to make the bindings survive assignments (`=`).

So this works, you need to create the properties `channelName` and `channelURL` in the root nodes of your `Guide.qml` abd your `ChannelViewer.qml`. Then, in each place inside those files, you use fully qualified identifiers: `id.propertyName`, which would be e.g `channelinfo.channelName` in the `ChannelInfo.qml`, `root.channelName` in the `ChannelViewer.qml` and an id you will need to set (e.g. root again) in your `Guid.qml` -> `root.channelName`.

> - Usage of fully qualified identifiers for bindings, which always include the `idOfTheObject.propertyName` helps to avoid problems. In some cases (positioning, anchoring, sizing) `parent` is ok, but you might not know what exactly is the parent)
> - Dynamic scoping is a blessing if you know exactly how and where the code will be used, e.g. if it is essentially a partial definition of a larger object, and will never be used in another context. But here you need to know that if the parent file changes the internal api, you need to adapt the child file accordingly. If you think, the file might be for reuse, avoid dynamic scoping and only reference what is defined inside the file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried this method before and didn't work . It says that channelName is a non-existent property. probably I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Oh yeah you're right. You have no `channelName` in your `ChannelViewer.qml` nor you do in your `Guide.qml`. You can only set properties of a files root node.

Comment: Do you have links to either the code or better the documentation of: `ChannelInfo`, `VlcVideoPlayer`? Try to avoid bindings to properties that are not declared in the same file as the one, where you set the binding up. Create properties in the files root node, to which you bind your internal properties. Then you can set them up properly when using the component.

Comment: ChannelInfo is my own code, i will edit my original post and include it. VLCVidoPlayer, this is the github for it https://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt
I tried setting up everything in the root node and same issue.

Comment: done what you edited and still same problem. It's driving me crazy.